# Create Lambda Function CRUD to RDS MySQL in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, lambda

I am investigating how to create functions, in Lambda, against MySQL. I have seen tutorials on the internet, but I can not do it. I've only been able to do the GET method.

How do I manage the variables, to make a DELETE or a PUT?

Currently, I did this function.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT,
  database : process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(null, result)
  });
};
```

Here it's the database

[image]

My Lambda Function

[image]

And my API Gateway

[image]

I hope to create a function to delete a record. It is not a productive environment, just to learn! I appreciate, if you help me! Regards!

Comment: could you do it?

Comment: Yes! I don t know if need changes! 

https://github.com/safernandez666/APILambdaToMySQL